# Can't store session data between pages

Tags: php, session, header

I have faced a problem in all of my php projects is that since i used OOP is that if there is a user submitting a form

when it goes to processing it and if it has an error i save a message in the session and redirect them to the same page

this is a sample and of course when it redirects it wipes all the fields that was there

like let's say i have a register form that had

```
<?php if(!empty($message)) { echo $message } ?>
<form action ="forms/register.php">
first name: <input type="text" name="first_name" />
username:<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="submit" value = "submit" />
</form>
```

and this is what the code in forms/register.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

 if(empty($first_name) || empty($username) {
    $session -> message("please fill in all the fields");
    redirect("../register.php");
 } else {
    // do something else like insert query
 }

 }
```

my problem is if first_name or user_name is empty and it redirects to register.php

and it echos the error message no problem in that

but the fields are empty the first_name and the user_name are empty

so the user has to fill it all again

so one of my friends suggested to save it in the session or something

so i would like to know if that is possible then how and what i mean by how so nobody would get it wrong, i mean the way not the code to just copy it and paste it

Thanks in advance

and sorry for being long and annoying

Comment: Well, apart from the missing closing bracket in the PHP after empty($username), the POST vars should be passing OK. Can you try a ghetto style print_r($_POST);exit; to see what's actually happening there? Also maybe analyze the headers you're sending with FireBug...

Comment: You seem to be using a class for `$session`. Without seeing its code we have no clue to help you. Please, sumarise the `$session` class and post it here. Also, are you using a framework like CakePHP or CodeIgniter?

Comment: Instead of using enters at random places, you might want to consider periods at the end of your sentences.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher it is posting fine my problem was is that when it redirects the inputs are empty

Comment: @rcdmk yes you are right about the class for the session and i am not using any framework or anything

Comment: mario and GolezTrol sorry i have very little knowledge about English because i am not from an English speaking country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store whatever values you want to keep persisted in the form after the page redirects in session variables, then retrieve those values on the form page and echo them in the `value` attribute of the form elements.

Comment: i guess i will have to store it like that then

$username = $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']

and when it redirects i will try

<input type="text" <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['username')) { echo value =\"$_SESSION['username']\" } ?> />

is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that should be right, except you left out the closing bracket in the `if` statement. It should be `if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))`

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start(); $_SESSION['nick'] = $_GET['nick'];
```

more / better examples:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what issue you exactly are facing (also what $session is inside your workflow?).
However, i recommend using PHP inbuild session support.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

From the above link itself:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
{
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
    echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
}
?>
```

Above code simply keeps track of page views. $_SESSION variable persists between page loads and you should be using the same for all your session requirements.

Comment: I am using a class that's all